# dragend event listener not firing in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

It won't even log to the console. I'm not sure what's going on here:

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.2, 173.3),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  streetViewControl: false
}

var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker();

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
// If the marker already exists, set it's position to null
    if (homeMarker) {
        homeMarker.setPosition(null);
    }

// Instantiate the marker again
  homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Your Home Location',
    draggable: true 
  });

// Set the input fields to the latitude and longitude
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();

    $('input#homeLat').val(latitude.toFixed(6));
    $('input#homeLong').val(longitude.toFixed(6));
 }); 

// What is wrong here?
google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, "dragend", function(event) {
 console.log('foo');        
});
```

Basically, what is meant to happen is that I want to fetch the coordinates from the new position of the marker, which can be changed via a click on the `map` and a drag of the marker itself. I've got the former working, but my `eventListener` for `dragend` doesn't seem to be firing at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alert while dragging, same code works for me.
getPosition() helps to get the current marker position

Try this,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, "dragend", function(event) {
     alert('map dragged');
     homeMarker.getPosition();
});
```

Comment: Where "r" (r.getPosition()) came from?